# $XD = DX$ then $X$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $D$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with diagonal entries $d_1, ..., d_n$ all distinct. Prove that if $XD = DX$ then $X$ is diagonal.

Not sure how to approach this, but here is my attempt,

denote $\underline{d_1} = \begin{pmatrix} d_1 \\ 0 \\... \\ ... \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\underline{d_n} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\... \\ ... \\ d_n \end{pmatrix}$ then $\{ \underline{d_1}, ... , \underline{d_n} \}$ is a basis of eigenvectors, and let $D = (\underline{d_1},...,\underline{d_n})$ then we know that since $\{ \underline{d_1}, ... , \underline{d_n} \}$ is a basis, then $D$ is invertible. We have $XD = DX \implies X = DXD^{-1}$ hence $X$ is diagonal. Is this correct, if not how would I go about it?

Comment: This is wrong, $XI_n = X = I_nX$ for every $X$. ($I_n$ means the identity $n\times n$ matrix here).

Comment: all $d_i$ are distinct

Comment: @Warz : It is still not true. Just take $X$ to be a Jordan block with zeros on the diagonal.

Comment: @Warz Ok. I must say though that putting the whole proposition except for one, crucial property into the title really does invite mistakes such as mine.

Comment: @fgp assumed that afterwards and changed the title (apologies), but I did print out the full question in the thread body.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan taking a look at what Jordon block matrices are in wikipedia, surely the statement that $XD = DX$ doesn't hold with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove the statement, simply calculate $XD=DX$ entrywise. One gets $x_{ij}d_j=d_ix_{ij}$ for every $i\ne j$.

Your proof is wrong and incomplete. While the diagonal entries of $D$ are distinct, one of them may be zero. So, one of the "eigenvector" you produce may be the zero vector.

In addition, you said "$X = DXD^{-1}$ **hence** $X$ is diagonal". Why? It seems to me that this is a leap of faith.

Comment: Thanks, I get the solution from there. Could I ask how you get $x_{ij}d_j = d_ix_{ij}$?

Comment: @Warz Just calculate $XD=DX$ *entrywise*. Given two square matrices $A$ and $B$, do you know how to calculate the $(i,j)$-th entry of $AB$?

Comment: $(XD)_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^nx_{ij}d_j$?

Comment: @Warz No. Let $C=AB$. Then $c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}$.

Comment: then I'm not sure how you'd get to $x_{ij}d_j = d_ix_{ij}$

Comment: @Warz Let $D=(\hat{d}_{ij})$, where $\hat{d}_{ii}=d_i$ and $\hat{d}_{ij}=0$ when $i\ne j$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_i$ an eigenvector of $D$. Then $DXv_i=XDv_i=X(d_iv_i)=d_iXv_i$, hence $Xv_i\in<v_i>$, the $d_i$-eigenspace of $D$.